# Error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\get_option()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7

hello i update of laravel 5.4 to 5.7 to 5.8 to 6 and finely to 7.14 and i see get_option error

```
public function user()
{
    $userCount = User::where('admin','0')->count();
    $adminCount = User::where('admin','1')->count();
    $buyerCount = Sell::distinct('buyer_id')->count('buyer_id');
    $sellerCount = Sell::distinct('user_id')->count('user_id');
    $dayRegister = User::where('create_at','>',strtotime('-'.get_option('chart_day_count',10).' day')+12600)->get();
    return view('admin.report.user',['userCount'=>$userCount,'adminCount'=>$adminCount,'buyerCount'=>$buyerCount,'sellerCount'=>$sellerCount,'dayRegister'=>$dayRegister]);
}
```

in laravel 5.4 i defined in helper method

```
function get_option($option,$default = null){
    if($result = \App\Models\Option::where('option',$option)->value('value'))
        return $result;
    else
        return $default;
}
```

but in laravel 7 not work!

Comment: if($result = \App\Models\Option::where('option',$option)->value('value')){
        return $result;
}
    else {
        return $default;
}

Comment: try with '{ }' on your returns

Comment: thank you for your answar but please help more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check your namespace

The error is telling you that `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\get_option()` is not a function. This means it is looking for the function in the current namespace. Did you include/require it from the wrong path?.

## Create a helper class

I don't have Laravel7 projects currently, but what I do in Laravel5 is create helper classes instead of plain functions. To follow your example:

Save this as `app/Helpers/OptionsHelper.php` or similar.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class OptionsHelper
{
  /**
   * Private constructor, `new` is disallowed by design.
   */
  private function __construct()
  { }

  public static function getOption($option, $default = null){
    if($result = \App\Models\Option::where('option', $option)->value('value')) {
      return $result;
    }
    else {
      return $default;
    }
  }
}
```

Import this helper with `use App\Helpers\OptionsHelper` and call `OptionsHelper::getOption` instead of `get_option`.

Comment: thank you it is work fine...in call function i problem

Comment: one question...i cant called this method in view ??   OptionsHelper::getOption('chart_day_count',10) 
eroor Class 'OptionsHelper' not found (View:

Comment: You should not do calls like this in the view directly.
Instead have the variable available in the view, so call the OptionsHelper from your controller to create the variable in the view.

Comment: help me please to call

Comment: i defined this    $getoption = OptionsHelper::getOption(); and passed to view but not work...eroor Too few arguments to function App\Helpers\OptionsHelper::getOption(),

Comment: No I mean `$chartDayCount = OptionsHelper::getOption('chart_day_count',10)` and then pass `$chartDayCount` to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Make function as public function and call the function using self::function_name();

Comment: Please do not answer with plain 1 liners. Be more specific. Also include some code if this will help the user to understand the solution corretly. As soon as you have enough reputation you could comments like this to the question. #

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.